# Button and form disappear in ipad (landscape)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm developing a responsive layout with Bootstrap 3, but I have a problem.

I use a login form at the top of the application, but I change its settings according to the screen size.

If the screen size using the properties for larger screens (lg and md), it shows the form, otherwise (xs and sm) shows only one button to login.

Then use the classes .visible-md and .visible-lg to show the form and .visible-xs and .visible-sm to display a button.

But when i'm test on the iPad (landscape), the formulário and button disappear.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! A code example demonstrating your problem, and maybe even a jsfiddle your bootply, will dramatically increase the chance for a helpful answer.

Comment: www.revistasuperfacil.com.br/teste

thanks

Comment: No, I mean, post your code targeting the problem in your question :) Edit the question, and insert the code that causes your problems. Without telepathy skills no one is able to answer your question, as it is now, no offense!

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions from @davidkonrad are helpful and as he pointed out, the easier you make it for others to see the issue, the more likely it is that you'll get help.

To get you started though, if you look in the head of your HTML at line 119 you have

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (max-width: 770px) {
        #form-login{ display: none; }
        #btn-login{ display:block; }
    }
```

The root cause of your problem is the line

```
#form-login{ display: none; }
```

Remove that and atleast your form won't disappear on you at certain viewports. After that you can work on the layout.

Good luck!